# django apps for changing user email with verification?

Tags: django, email, registration, profile

I already use django-registration : you can register with an email verification, you can reset password with an email confirmation but there is no way to change user's email with an email verification.

Do you know a django application which gives the ability to change user's email address by sending to the new address a verification e-mail ?

Comment: Hi, did you find a good solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this app:

http://github.com/jtauber/django-email-confirmation/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this app. (I wrote for the exact purpose)

https://github.com/un33k/django-emailmgr

It works well with django-registration as the email provided during the registration would be the primary email address and already verified.

the user can then add more email addresses and confirm each one. Once a new email is confirmed, then it can be promoted to the primary address. Then the old primary address can be deleted.

This way you ensure that users always have at least one verified email address associated with their profile.

If you want to see a live example, then you can do that on http://outsourcefactor.com by
creating an account (django-registration), activating it, login, and look at the email tab under your account settings. Once you are done, you can delete the account.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You don't usually provide email verification to reset a password, since this is done at the signup stage.
Django does however have the ability to send the reset password to the user in an email, after they have requested their password to be reset through a view.

Checkout the documentation here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset

EDIT:

I found and app that is able to reset the email of a user account, it does way more that just that (which may be a drawback) but could be useful:

http://code.google.com/p/django-profile/#Features

Comment: The question was not about password reset, but about email address changing.

Comment: Ah I apologise, I jumped to a conclusion to early. My only suggestion would be that email addresses should most likely be tied to an account.

Upon a quick search for a solution I wasn't able to find an app to do the task. Most likely it might be something to rethink, or to build yourself. That is unless someone else has a more exacting answer.

Sorry for the confusion with my initial answer.
Marcus

Comment: I have found an app that does have what you were looking for I will add it to the question as an edit.