# Send confirmation email when changing the email in Django

Tags: django, registration, django-registration

I'm currently using `django-registration`, and it is working well (with some tricks). When the user registers, he has to check his/her mail and click on the activation link. That's fine, but...

What if the user changes the email? I would like to send him/her an email in order to confirm that he is the owner of the email address...

Is there an application, snippet, or something **that would save me the time of writing it by myself**?

Comment: Try these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296846/django-apps-for-changing-user-email-with-verification

Comment: If none of that work, I mean the time spending tweaking two apps to work together might as well spent in writing a small views that reads in the hashed verification code, and adds a status field called "verifying" in the user model class. Until the verification is done, the user is locked.

Answer (score 6):

I've faced the same issue recently. And I didn't like the idea of having another app/plugin for just that.

You can achieve that by, listening to `User` model's singles(`pre_save`, `post_save`) and using `RegistrationProfile`:

**signals.py:**

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, RequestSite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile


# Check if email change
@receiver(pre_save,sender=User)
def pre_check_email(sender, instance, **kw):
    if instance.id:
        _old_email = instance._old_email = sender.objects.get(id=instance.id).email
        if _old_email != instance.email:
            instance.is_active = False

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def post_check_email(sender, instance, created, **kw):
    if not created:
        _old_email = getattr(instance, '_old_email', None)
        if instance.email != _old_email:
            # remove registration profile
            try:
                old_profile = RegistrationProfile.objects.get(user=instance)
                old_profile.delete()
            except:
                pass

            # create registration profile
            new_profile = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_profile(instance)

            # send activation email
            if Site._meta.installed:
                site = Site.objects.get_current()
            else:
                site = RequestSite(request)
            new_profile.send_activation_email(site)
```

So whenever a `User`'s email is changed, the user will be deactivated and an activation email will be send to the user.

Comment: For the `post_save` don't you need to pass the request or some such?

Comment: One flaw with this might be the fact that if a user updates their email address to an incorrect address by mistake, then doesn't receive the email, they will be left locked out?

Comment: don't like the idea of making the users account inactive